# Slow Boot in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

So I recently wiped out my HDD on my Windows 10 laptop and installed Ubuntu because I have been using it on all of my other devices. Since the beginning of my install I've had slow boot. ~ 2-3 minutes whereas Windows was 20 seconds to 1 minute. I ran systemd-analyze blame and got these as the longest times:

```
     1min 9.032s systemd-journal-flush.service
     59.534s dev-sda3.device
     49.667s systemd-udevd.service
     48.068s snap-core-4917.mount
     47.488s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
     45.831s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
     42.419s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
     40.883s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-101.mount
     39.953s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
     38.731s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
     36.265s snap-core-4830.mount
     34.965s snap-core-4486.mount
     33.822s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
     32.353s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
     31.325s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
     30.223s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-64.mount
     28.056s snap-simplenote-50.mount
     26.239s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-45.mount
     25.556s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
     19.801s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      9.469s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      8.277s snapd.service
      7.745s udisks2.service
      6.820s NetworkManager.service
      6.065s user@120.service
      5.735s heimdal-kcm.service
      5.245s plymouth-start.service
      5.227s dev-loop18.device
      4.515s dev-loop10.device
      4.508s accounts-daemon.service
      4.294s networkd-dispatcher.service
      4.042s ModemManager.service
      3.985s dev-loop14.device
      3.787s tlp.service
      3.716s dev-loop7.device
      3.659s dev-loop17.device
      3.658s dev-loop16.device
```

and I also ran systemd-analyze time and got:

```
Startup finished in 8.019s (firmware) + 5.449s (loader) + 5.260s (kernel) + 1min 49.085s (userspace) = 2min 7.815s
graphical.target reached after 1min 45.295s in userspace
```

And from the analyze balme, I see that SDA3 is taking 59 seconds, SDA3 is my parition mounted at root. I have two other paritions, SDA1 - EFI, and SDA2 - Swap. I've seen online about adding noresume to grub - but I thought that was only for no swap parition, so should i try it anyway?

Why is it taking so long to boot then on Ubuntu? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

That is required to flush old logs. You can disable it, but what I’d recommend you is change the vacuum time:

sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=5d

will delete all logs but retain the last 5 days logs. This way your system never will be sluggish because of the big sized logs.

You’ll notice that a lot of space is freed.

Tell us if it helps.

Oh, you can also setup the the journald, the config file /etc/systemd/journald.conf has some configuration fields:

## SystemMaxUse=

## SystemKeepFree=

## SystemMaxFileSize=

Check man journald.conf for more info.

Cheers!